# Css issue for IE8 - Odd space appearing between 2 divs in the header

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

You can view the issue on:

http://www.caterinaligato.com/

We can't reproduce the issue on IE7 or any of the Firefox versions. Using the DeveloperTool on IE8 its showing that the padding is inside the `<div id="bannerArea">`, however, we have tried `#bannerArea * { padding:0; margin:0; display:block; }` and that hasn't helped.

Please note that the 'Compatibility View' is off.

If anyone has any advise that would be great!

Comment: Psychic healer, huh?  Maybe ask the client how the problem gets resolved and who solves it?

Answer (score 1):

Start by adding `overflow: hidden;` to your BannerArea class. I'm not convinced that the star hack is necessarily the best option either.  I would suggest removing that until it's proven that you absolutely need it.

Finally, make sure your `<a>` tag has its content all on one line.  IE has historically had a degree of difficulty with the correct layout when anchor tags have line-breaks in the markup, displaying whitespace where there shouldn't be any.

Your line of markup:

```
<div id="bannerArea"><span class="bannerContainer first"><a href="#" class='banner-95 bannerImage' title='' rel='nofollow'><img src="/media/pics/site/imagecache/683C6A596432B154340F913300D76915.jpg" width="958" height="346" alt=''/></a> </span></div>
```

...splits the  tag across three lines, which may be contributing to the issue.

Answer (score 0):

use float:left for "bannerArea" it will reduce the white space in IE8, But the position will move right, need to reset the position.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this is happening because of your drop-down menu. If you add overflow:hidden to you "bannerArea" div, then the white space vanishes, but the placement is ruined. When added overflow:hidden to "nv" div, the image came back to it's place. So you have take care of the drop-down menu. Perhaps you can use scrip drop-down instead of pure css?